# Why does Elastic Beanstalk create new EC2 instances when I change my EB settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I make a configuration change in the Amazon EB interface (for instance, changing the EC2 key/pair or the monitoring interval), EB will shut down the existing EC2 instance and create a new one. Why doesn't it just use the existing EC2 instance? Is there any implication to the accumulation of terminated EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

Some EC2 instance properties (Key Pair and others) are immutable, so Elastic Beanstalk needs to create a new instance with identical properties, except for the changed property. There is no implication to the accumulation of terminated instances, but it will charge for a new instance. For example, if you change the property 2 times in an hour, you would be charged 3 hours.

Comment: Do these instances ever disappear from my instance list?

Comment: Yes, they do after a while.